# How is Remix OS (or Phoenix OS ) different from the Android that runs on regular Android phones?

Tags: android-x86, android-pc

Remix OS (or Phoenix OS ) is a good way to run Android on PC but  what are the basic differences between the Android-on-pc OSs and a regular Android which runs on a regular Android device.

Comment: Isn't the Tablet/Desktop-friendly UI already different enough? What other difference do you hope to know?

Comment: I mean differences in the OS structure. At first I thought they had differences in the launcher and system UI only but now I know that it is not the only difference.

Comment: Well I don't know of any... Mind sharing what you already know (and the source)?